# Delphi - Manage a TList with dynamic array

Tags: delphi

I've a component for plot a spline, the argument for Spline procedure in an array of TPoint.
Now, I want to create n dynamic array of TPoint, save this in a TList and after recall for plot the splines.

P.S. Delphi XE5

Example:

```
var
  l: TList;

procedure CreateSpline;
var i, x: byte;
    p: TPoint;
    a: array of TPoint;
begin
    l := TList.Create;

    for x := 0 to 9 do  // create 10 splines
    begin
        SetLength(a, Random(10) + 5);   Each spline has 5<n<15 points
        for i := 0 to High(a) do
        begin
            p.X := Random(200) - 100;   // X coord
            p.Y := Random(200) - 100;   // Y coord
            a[i] := p;                  // add point to array
        end;
        l.Add(a);                       // add array to TList
    end;
end;

procedure DrawSpline;
var i: byte;
    a: array of TPoint;
begin
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
        a := l[i];
        xyPlot.Spline(a);  // Draw the spline (xyPlot is the graphic component)
    end;
end;
```

... and don't work.  :-(

Comment: Instead of a `TList`, you should use a `TList<TArray<TPoint>>` (uses `Generics.Collections`).

Comment: Thanks, now is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-Generic [`System.Classes.TList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TList) is just a container of raw pointers, it has no concept of what it holds.  Dynamic arrays are reference-counted, and `TList` will not manage the reference counts for you, so you have to do it manually to ensure the reference counts are incremented while the arrays are in the list, eg:

```pascal
ar
  l: TList;

procedure CreateSpline;
var
  i, x: byte;
  p: TPoint;
  a: TArray<TPoint>;
  aptr: Pointer;
begin
  l := TList.Create;

  for x := 0 to 9 do  // create 10 splines
  begin
    SetLength(a, Random(10) + 5);   // Each spline has 5<n<15 points
    for i := 0 to High(a) do
    begin
      p.X := Random(200) - 100;     // X coord
      p.Y := Random(200) - 100;     // Y coord
      a[i] := p;                    // add point to array
    end;
    TArray<TPoint>(aptr) := a;
    try
      l.Add(aptr);                  // add array to TList
    except
      TArray<TPoint>(aptr) := nil;
      raise;
    end;
    a := nil;
  end;
end;

{ alternatively:

procedure CreateSpline;
var
  i, x: byte;
  p: TPoint;
  a: TArray<TPoint>;
begin
  l := TList.Create;

  for x := 0 to 9 do  // create 10 splines
  begin
    SetLength(a, Random(10) + 5);   // Each spline has 5<n<15 points
    for i := 0 to High(a) do
    begin
      p.X := Random(200) - 100;     // X coord
      p.Y := Random(200) - 100;     // Y coord
      a[i] := p;                    // add point to array
    end;
    l.Add(Pointer(a));              // add array to TList
    Pointer(a) := nil;
  end;
end;
}

procedure DrawSpline;
var
  i: byte;
  a: TArray<TPoint>;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    a := TArray<TPoint>(l[i]);
    xyPlot.Spline(a);  // Draw the spline (xyPlot is the graphic component)
  end;
end;

...

// later, you need to decrement the refcounts before freeing/clearing the TList...

var
  i: byte;
  aptr: Pointer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    aptr := l[i];
    TArray<TPoint>(aptr) = nil;
  end;
  l.Free;
end;
```

A better solution is to use the Generic [`System.Generics.Collections.TList<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) instead, where `T` is `TArray<TPoint>`.  Then the reference counts will be managed properly for you, eg:

```pascal
ar
  l: TList<TArray<TPoint>>;

procedure CreateSpline;
var
  i, x: byte;
  p: TPoint;
  a: TArray<TPoint>;
begin
  l := TList<TArray<TPoint>>.Create;

  for x := 0 to 9 do  // create 10 splines
  begin
    SetLength(a, Random(10) + 5);   // Each spline has 5<n<15 points
    for i := 0 to High(a) do
    begin
      p.X := Random(200) - 100;     // X coord
      p.Y := Random(200) - 100;     // Y coord
      a[i] := p;                    // add point to array
    end;
    l.Add(a);                       // add array to TList
  end;
end;

procedure DrawSpline;
var
  i: byte;
  a: TArray<TPoint>;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    a := l[i];
    xyPlot.Spline(a);  // Draw the spline (xyPlot is the graphic component)
  end;
end;

...

l.Free;
```